# How to type "line1", "line2", "line3".... using for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

For example, I want to generate below output using a "for" loop, having the for loop automatically populate the number at the end of the word `line`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

Comment: Share your attempt. Till what number should it loop?

Comment: for i in range(1,8):
    print(f"line{i}")

Comment: Do you even know how to use for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use f strings.\

```
n = 7
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(f"line{i}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with "f-strings" and the `range()` class object in a `for` loop:

[**for_loop_basic_demo.py:**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/for_loop_basic_demo.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

END_NUM = 7
for i in range(1, END_NUM + 1):
    print(f"line{i}")
```

Run command:

```sh
./for_loop_basic_demo.py
```

Output:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

### Going further: 3 ways to print

The 3 ways I'm aware of to print formatted strings in Python are:

1. formatted string literals; AKA: "f-strings"
2. the `str.format()` method, or
3. the C `printf()`-like `%` operator

[Here are demo prints](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/for_loop_basic_demo.py) with all 3 of those techniques to show each one for you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

END_NUM = 7
for i in range(1, END_NUM + 1):
    # 3 techniques to print:

    # 1. newest technique: formatted string literals; AKA: "f-strings"
    print(f"line{i}")

    # 2. newer technique: `str.format()` method
    print("line{}".format(i))

    # 3. oldest, C-like "printf"-style `%` operator print method
    # (sometimes is still the best method, however!)
    print("line%i" % i)

    print() # print just a newline char
```

Run cmd and output:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/python$ ./for_loop_basic_demo.py 
line1
line1
line1

line2
line2
line2

line3
line3
line3

line4
line4
line4

line5
line5
line5

line6
line6
line6

line7
line7
line7
```

### References:

1. ***** This is an *excellent* read, and I highly recommend you read and study it!: [Python String Formatting Best Practices](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)
2. Official Python documentation for all "Built-in Functions". Get used to referencing this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

   1. The `range()` class in particular, which creates a `range` object which allows the above `for` loop iteration: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: @AkshayL, please remember to upvote all answers you find useful, and click the checkmark to mark one answer you like the best as the "right" answer. Upvoting is how you motivate answerers to keep on answering.